# AngularJS - Exclude a Particular AJAX Request From Having a Request Interceptor Attached to It?

Tags: angularjs

I have a request interceptor defined in my Angular app that looks like:

```
precinct.factory('httpRequestInterceptor', function($rootScope){
    return {
        request: function(config){
            if($rootScope.myToken){
                config.headers['custom-token'] = $rootScope.myToken;
            }
            return config;
        }
    }
});
precinct.config(function($httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');
});
```

The above attaches an API token to all my AJAX requests and allows me to authenticate between my Angular app and my backend endpoints.

Every once in a while, I will send an AJAX request to a 3rd party API endpoint which does not support the `custom-token` header.

How do I exclude that particular request from having the header attached to it by the interceptor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy option... add a flag to the `$http` config that tells your interceptor to ignore it, eg

```
request: function(config) {
  if (!config.skipInterceptor && $rootScope.myToken) {
    // and so on
  }
  return config;
}
```

and

```
$http.get('http://some.external.api', {
  skipInterceptor: true
})
```

Comment: great answer. i learned something. i would have probably did an array of domain names and checked if the request domain was in the array with `indexOf()`. this is much smarter than that idea.

Comment: @r3wt was going to suggest that as another option but it would become a maintenance pain-point

Comment: is it cool if i bug you to answer a question for me? I've written a small utility library with angular, and the synchronous iterator function i wrote always skips the first element in the array, i can't figure out why.

Comment: no this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42287362/synchronous-iterator-skips-first-item-in-array