# synchronous iterator skips first item in array

Tags: javascript

it's a part of a utility library for angular, but i'll copy just the function its self here to make it easy to reproduce the problem. the problem is that for some reason there is 1 less item in the output than there is in the array. for example, array length of 1000 only outputs 999 elements in results array. why?

**the function:**

```
var sync = function( items, eachFn, callbackFn ){

    var results = [], 
        errors = [];

    function next(error,result){
        if(error) {
        errors.push(error);
    }
        if(result) {
        results.push(result);
    }
        if(items.length == 0){
            return callbackFn(errors,results);
        }else{
            eachFn(items.shift(),next);
        }
    };

    next();

};
```

**the repro:**

```
var array = new Array(1000).fill(0);// 1000 item array

var i = -1;

sync(array,function(item,next){
    i++;
    next(null,i);
},function(errors,results){
    console.log(results.length === 1000);// but its 999, why?
});
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/r3wt/x2Lp5azn/)

Comment: initializing the array with 0 brings 1000 items instead of -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first iteration you are passing `0` as result.

```
if(result) {
    results.push(result);
}
```

will be `false` (`Boolean(0)` is `false`) so `0` is never added to the `results` array.

---

For `result` you can just compare it against `undefined`:

```
if (result !== undefined)
```

For `error`, you can use loose comparison against `null`, which handles `null` *and* `undefined`:

```
if (error != null)
```

Comment: so i should check for undefined instead `result != undefined` please add this to your answer (for future readers to reference). also for error it is necessary to check for both null and undefined, since it would be impossible to call next with result and without error, so `[null,undefined].indexOf(error) != -1` should be the check for the error.

Comment: once you add the additional info, i will accept your answer.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. I thought the function was from a third party library.

Comment: its my own personal utility library. got tired of writing these sync/async iterators over and over so i just wrote a small utility library, and add small tools as needed

Answer (score 2):

It's not pushing on this line when i is 0 :

```
 if(result) {
```

Answer (score 1):

`0` is falsy in javascript. Thus when doing:

```
if(result)
    results.push(result);
```

if `result` is `0` then it won't get pushed. To check if `result` is defined use this:

```
if(result !== undefined)
    results.push(result);
```